# Travelling UK without wife

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, german-residents

I am living in Germany. I have applied 6 month EEA UK permit. I got that one. I have been to the UK with my wife according to condition that she must be travelling with me or accompany with me. But now I left the UK alone and my wife stayed in the UK.

Now I want to go back the UK.
Can I travel alone. And I have successful presettle status. I have 5 year family member card but my card is in the UK.
My wife got that card. Can I travel to the UK alone. She also coming to receive me in the UK airport.

Comment: Get your wife to courier your card to you

Comment: @Traveller that won't be necessary as he has an EEA family permit sticker in his passport (unless I misunderstand the question).

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question, at least not to me, precisely which documents you now have and where exactly they are.  It sounds like you have a valid EEA family permit and you want to know if you can use that to travel to the UK to join your wife who is already in the UK, and the answer to that question is *yes.*  An EEA family permit may be used under the following conditions.  The first point applies in this case:

> Eligibility
>
> The EEA citizen you’re joining must either:
>
> - be in the UK already
> - be travelling with you to the UK within 6 months of the date of your application

Source: https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eea-family-permit

Comment: It seems to me the actual card (or papers) is in the UK, with his wife. I assume he will need it to get on the flight (or a visa instead.)

Comment: @Willeke the EEA family permit is a passport sticker.

Comment: "I have 5 year family member card but my card is in the UK." (from the question.)

Comment: @Willeke I assume that to be a German card, the basis for OP's residence in Germany, but even if it is not, the card is apparently in addition to an EEA family permit ("I have applied 6 month EEA UK permit. I got that one," also from the question).

Comment: yes i have valid eea family permit and my wife is in uk.first time when i entered into uk i was with my wife .and now i am going alone to uk and my wife she is in uk .question is that do i need some proof that she is living in uk.

Comment: @HarpreetSingh you say she will be at the airport.  If the officer requires proof that she is in the UK you can say "she is waiting for me at the airport."  If they don't believe you, they can call her and ask her to come meet them.  If she has been in the UK for more than 3 months, you may need to prove that she is a "qualified person."  If she has a job, then she is a qualified person.